# Circle not going invisible when triggered

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am learning Lua and using Corona (http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) to make my first "Game". It is going OK, but my code isn't working as it should.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Your code here
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
local random = math.random
local cwidth = display.contentWidth local cheight = display.contentHeight
local starTable = { }

for i = 0,400 do
table.insert (starTable, display.newCircle(random(0,cwidth), random(0,cheight), random(0.8, 2.3)))
end

local function reset( event )
    for i = 0,#starTable do
        starTable[i].isVisible = false
    end
end

local function animate(event)
    for i = 0,#starTable do
        if random(0, 155) == 5 then
            starTable[i].isVisible = true
        end
    end
    timer.performWithDelay(150, reset)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", animate);

--This is the fade in at the start

local rect = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.viewableContentHeight)
rect:setFillColor(0,0,0)

transition.to(rect, {time=2750, alpha=0})

--It should be on the bottom of this file, so it is always on top.
```

The problem is that the circles aren't flickering as they should be. I know all the functions are triggering if I put a render in the reset function (e.g       display.newText("test", 50, 50, nil, 53)), it will render, but it doesn't flicker.

It give me this error:

```
?: iRuntime error ...\users\david\documents\corona projects\test\main.lua:19: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value) stack traceback: [C]: ? ...\users\david\documents\corona projects\test\main.lua:19: in function
'_listener' ?: in function <?:514> ?: iRuntime error ...\users\david\documents\corona projects\test\main.lua:19: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)
stack traceback: [C]: ? ...\users\david\documents\corona projects\test\main.lua:19: in function '_listener' ?: in function <?:514> ?: i
```

**EDIT: Fixed it**

Fixed it -- I forgot to assign it a pos.

Changed

```
table.insert (starTable, display.newCircle(random(0,cwidth), random(0,cheight), random(0.8, 2.3)))
```

to

```
table.insert (starTable, i, display.newCircle(random(0,cwidth), random(0,cheight), random(0.8, 2.3)))
```

Comment: Instead of editing your question, answer it, and mark your answer as correct. Otherwise the question still appears on the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate a position in starTable where you want to put your circle otherwise it will be inserted at the end of table:

```
table.insert (starTable, position, display.newCircle(random(0,cwidth), random(0,cheight), random(0.8, 2.3)))
```

More about Lua tables:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial
http://www.lua.org/pil/19.2.html